# Getting Wrong Subtraction Results for Single DataType VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

`Dim StartXRatioBetween2Lines As Single = Math.Max(l1StartAt.x, l2StartAt.x) - Math.Min(l1StartAt.x, l2StartAt.x)`

`StartXRatioBetween2Lines` is returning me a wrong results, both `l1StartAt.x` and `l2StartAt.x` are of a `Single` data type

Here are the values for my Xs:

`l1StartAt.x` is `219.89958190917969`

`l2StartAt.x` is `219.89959716796875`

`StartXRatioBetween2Lines` is returning me `1.52587891E-05`

Shouldn't I be seeing value less than `0.1` for `StartXRatioBetween2Lines`?

Comment: 1.52 -05 = 0.0000152

Comment: @CruleD thanks! yea I can confirm that with a simple comparison between this number and 0.1. You should post it as answer so I can accept it

Comment: You are extremely fortunate to be getting a usable answer from this operation.  Single precision is only accurate to ca. 7 or 8 significant digits, which corresponds to the 5th decimal place in your original numbers.  You might reasonably get just about any answer from 1e-5 to 2e-5 if the operation were performed entirely in single precision (the fact that you get an exact result suggests to me that it's actually being done in double precision and then converted back to single).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "E-05" at the end of that number is saying that your number is being multiplied by 10^(-5), similar to the notation on a scientific/graphing calculator. Your number is much less than 0.1, it isn't wrong.

Here's another question about the subject that explains why the "E" is used in place of the "10^": https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6273/what-does-e-mean-in-9-0122222900391e-5